# Will any damage occur if I remove or plug in a device to SATA port with computer switched on?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, 64-bit, sata, physical-damage

Is it likely that there would be any physical damage if I did this:

- First I removed a hard drive from a SATA port but still had the power supply pluged in to my hard drive.
- I turned my computer on.
- And then plugged the hard drive in to the SATA port with my computer on.

Comment: ALL SATA devices are designed to be hot swap-able.  However, not all SATA controllers, support this feature.  Your question in it's current form cannot be answered, since you provided, nothing that specifically identifies your hardware.  You should edit your question and improve the quality and clarify your question.  You should remove the random quoting your list though.  The meta of you apologizing for your English doesn't belong in your question body.

Answer (score 0):

Physical damage is unlikely.

Software damage is possible, but that is the type of damage easier to repair.

As Ramhound notes in his comments, SATA devices (specifically their connectors) are designed to be hot-swappable.

If you look at a SATA connector you'll see some of the PINS are longer than the others. These will, obviously, have the first contact when connected, and these allow the devices to be connected and disconnected safely while power is still applied.